# Display a message with qTip2 on a TD element

Tags: javascript, qtip2

I'm using handsontable and qTip. So I want to display a message on some cells. So I'm using `.qTip` on an element cell :

```
$(hot.getCell(jsonobject[item-2],jsonobject[item-1])).qtip({...});
```

The method `getCell` returns TD element for given row, col if it is rendered on screen.

So when I display it in the console, I have my element : `<td class="red">`

But I have an error :

> TypeError: $(...).qtip is not a function

I don't understand why because I have my TD element.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? I think it is a fair question, well written and easy to understand. `getCell()` actually returns an element as described, so `qtip()` should work on its return value.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks ;) I know, that's why I don't understand why it doesn't work :/

Comment: Do you have `qtip.js` included *before* the javascript that uses that function?